# Bootstrap picture within a navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with a picture i want to be used instead of a colored background.

But it just gives me a plain white background for some reason.

I can't seem to find the error but i will still try. I hope someone can help me with this issue since im still learning HTML, CSS & PHP properly!

CODE:

```css
<?php
// CSS Fil:





?>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Jquery css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<!-- Fontawesome.io CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
 html {
   position: relative;
   min-height: 100%;
 }
 body {
   /* Margin bottom by footer height */
   margin-bottom: 60px;
 }
 .footer {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
   height: 60px;
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
 }
 

 
 body {
    background-image: url("images/vortrex-bg.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;  
 }
 
 .footer {
  background: none;
        padding: 20px;
 }
 .footer-p {
  color: black;
  
 }
 .footer-link {
  color: red;
 }
 .footer-link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkred;
 }
 .navbar-default {
  background-image: url(../images/128-198.png);
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: solid;
 }
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
 }
 
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    color: darkgrey;
 }
 
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
 color: none;
 }
 
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav .active > a,
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav .active > a:hover {
  color: black;
  background: darkgrey !important;
 }
 .img-circle {
 margin: -7px;
 }  
    .side-box-right {
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        float: right;
        border: solid;
        border-color: black;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-image: url(../images/128-198.jpg);
        
    }
    .side-box-left {
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 100px;
        float: right;
        border: solid;
        border-color: black;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: darkgrey;
    }
    .nyheder {
        border: solid;
        background: darkgrey;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

</style>
```

```html
<?php include('config/setup.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <?php include('config/css.php'); ?>
  <?php include('config/js.php'); ?>
  
  <title>Home | Vortrex</title>
   
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="side-box-left">
     Teamspeak3 Class
    <?php
    /* try
     {
        
       // show server as online
       echo "Server Status: online<br />\n";
       echo "Server IP: " . $ts3->getAdapterHost() . ":" . $ts3->virtualserver_port . "<br />\n";
       echo "Server Name: " . $ts3->virtualserver_name . "<br />\n";
       echo "Server Uptime: " . TeamSpeak3_Helper_Convert::seconds($ts3->virtualserver_uptime) . "<br />\n";
       echo "Server Version: " . TeamSpeak3_Helper_Convert::version($ts3->virtualserver_version) . "<br />\n";
       echo "Current Clients: " . $ts3->virtualserver_clientsonline . " / " . $ts3->virtualserver_maxclients . "<br />\n";
     }
     catch(Exception $e)
     {
       // grab errors and show server as offline
       echo "Server Status: offline<br />\n";
     } */
    ?>
    </div>
   </div>
  <!-- RIGHT HERE --> 
          <div class="col-md-8">  
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-circle" alt="Brand" src="images/logo.png" height="32" width="32"></a></div>
      <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="statistik.php">Statistikker</a></li>
      <li><a href="/forum">Forum</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                        <li><a href="shop.php">Shop</a></li>
                        <li><a href="bans/index.php">Ban List</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav><!-- Slutningen af navbaren -->
     
    <div class="nyheder">
     
     <!-- Overskrift på forsiden! -->
     
     <h1 align="center">Velkommen til Vortrex</h1>
     
     <!-- Overskrift på forsiden! -->
     
     <!-- I mellen <p> og </p> skrives hvad der skal stå på forsiden! -->
     <br>
     <br>
     <h3 align="center">Nyheder</h1>
     <p align="center">
      
      <?php #SKRIV HERUNDER! ?>
      
     
                        
                        
      <?php #SKRIV HEROVER! ?>
     </p>
     <!-- I mellen <p> og </p> skrives hvad der skal stå på forsiden! -->
   
                </div>
      
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
   <div class="side-box-right">
   <?php
   
   $q = "SELECT * FROM server";
   $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    
    if($r) {
     
    
     while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
     
     $online = $rows['online'];
     $status = $rows['status'];
        
                        
      if($status == "Online") {
                            echo "<h3 align='center'><font color='green'>$status</font><br>$online / 200</h3>";
                            echo "<h4><strong>mc.vortrex.dk</strong></h4>";
                            } else {
                            echo "<h3 align='center'><font color='red'>$status</font></h3>";
                            echo "<h4><strong>mc.vortrex.dk</strong></h4>";
                            }
                         }
                        } else {
                        echo "<h2>Der skette en fejl der gjorde serverens status ikke kunne vises!</h2>";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "<h4>Kontakt et staff medlem!";

                        }

                        ?>

   </div>
  </div> 
</div> 
</div>
    
    <?php include(D_TEMPLATE.'/footer.php'); ?> 
    
    <!--<div id="console-debug">
     Test debug window
    </div>-->

 </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 different paths to the images folder in your code

```
body {
    background-image: url("images/vortrex-bg.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;  
    }
```

and

```
.navbar-default {
        background-image: url(../images/128-198.png);
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: solid;
    }
```

so you need to modify one of them and see what changes

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didnt see this as my software used to code told me to use ../images/<file> but i guess i have to be more focused next time! But thanks a lot man (Y)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have to remember the hierarchy of your CSS code.  It looks as if you are in conflict with your styles. The hierarchy is as follows: 1.In-line Attributes 2.ID Attributes 3.Class Attributes 4,Elements

You are also calling in a lot of CSS stylesheets and then adding your own to it. I would first play with your double call:

```
body {
background-image: url("images/vortrex-bg.png");
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;  
}
```

and

```
.navbar-default {
    background-image: url(../images/128-198.png);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid;
}
```

Then check to make sure it is not interfering with what you are calling in through your stylesheets. Then take notice that you have no ID Attributes and only Classes. Think of what you want to take precedence and use the hierarchy to your advantage.